# Issue with passing parameters in angular js custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing some issues with passing parameters in angular js custom filter. I've the following search bar and ng-repeat :-

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search your contacts" ng-model="query">

<div class= "mylist_ul" ng-repeat="x in value | filter: query : searchFor">
    <span>{{x.name}}</span>
    <span>{{x.email}}</span>
    <span>{{x.age}}</span>
</div>
```

Here's my searchFor custom filter function :-

```
 $scope.searchFor = function (actual, expected) {
  console.log(actual + ' ' + expected);
}
```

When I search for a character 'a' for instance, I see in console :-

Tom a
tom@gmail.com a
21
[object Object] a

John a
john@gmail.com a
22
[object Object] a

Why is it taking everything inside the "mylist_ul" div and pairing it with the search parameter ? Shouldn't it just pass the object itself ?

Comment: What do you want to do with your angular's filter?

Comment: I would like to see if the typed string in the input text box is a substring of any of the names in mylist_ul (x.name) & return the matched list.